# Wordpress popular posts replaces img src with data-src?

Tags: wordpress, image

I am having a weird problem with WordPress popular posts plugin.

I create a php template to be assigned to a page and all images appear broken. With the same code on another site they look fine. It also looks fine on a regular page without this template. The file is located in the child theme of both sites but works only on the first.

I noticed that only where I have problem the regular src is replaced with data-src:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVSpP.png)

If I change it in the console the images displays correctly. The question is how I make the replacement in the site.

What I tried:
- Disabling all plugins that may affect this;
- Changing the output.php on WordPress popular posts, replacing all of the strings where i found data-src. Nothing changes.
- Applying the shotcode instead of array

Comment: data-src is used by lazyLoad for example. Do you have any lazy load on your page?

Comment: it was on but i disabled this option first when the problem occur - didn't solve the problem

Comment: I never used the plugin in question myself, but I found this:
Alternatively, you can also just deactivate the new Lazy Loading feature via Settings > WordPress Popular Posts > Tools under Thumbnails.

Is that the option you disabled? Are you sure you're not using lazy load from another plugin aswell? WP Rocket or some cache-plugin?

Comment: Yes, i disiabled everything related to caching and performance optimisation and disabled this specific setting. I am only using CDN (Cloudflare)